# Does the sufficiency of an ID-card for travelling abroad depend on the airline?

Tags: air-travel, passports, paperwork

I'm from the Netherlands and will be travelling to Turkey very soon. On my ID-card it says that it allows me to travel to Turkey (i.e. I don't need a passport). However, on the website of the airline I'm flying with it says that I do need a passport. So now I'm panicking a bit, since there's no way to arrange a passport at such short notice, and I was under the impression that I could travel to Turkey with just an ID-card.

So my question is: is this possible? Can it be that I can enter Turkey with just an ID-card, but that the airline still requires me to have a passport regardless?

Edit: I called them (already before posting this question), but it wasn't very helpful. The conversation went something like this

- Me: Do I need a pasport to fly from the Netherlands to Turkey?
- Them: Yes you need a passport
- Me: Even if an ID-card is sufficient for getting into Turkey?
- Them: Hold please...
- Them (20 secs later): We don't know, this is not our responsibility

So after that not so helpful conversation I came to this site to ask for more information. I'll update this answer either after I'm denied or after I arrived on my destination.

Comment: Of course they can. The airline's terms and conditions are not necessarily related to the requirements for immigration in your destination country.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Oke. Do you think there's any chance for me to still get on the plane even without a passport or is there basically 0 chance?

Comment: @pnuts Pegasus airlines

Comment: @pnuts Thanks a lot for looking that all up! I already called them, but they didn't know either... At first they said I needed a passport, but then when I mentioned that I don't need one to enter Turkey they didn't know anymore. I do have baggage though, so I think I'll have to go through security no matter what... Since I'm a very inexperienced flyer I know nothing about this stuff. Do you have enough flying experience to be able to judge what my chances are here?

Comment: @pnuts The site says all is oke, but I could not choose Pegasus airlines as my carrier for some reason; it wasn't in the list. But I'm hoping it's like you say: they just say you need a passport to respect all possible regulations, but in practice they don't enforce it, they just put it in there to be sure that in case it is actually necessary it was in the contract. (I might be a bit overly optimistic here but there's not much else I can do at this point...)

Comment: @pnuts Thanks so much for helping me and for the encouragement. I'm flying in around 30 hours from now, and I'll be sure to let you know how it went.

Comment: Why dont call them to ask

Comment: @Him see 5 msges previously; i called them but they didnt know

Comment: The airline can deny you boarding for a wide range of reasons, plenty of which have no connection to whether you have a passport on you or not. So, purely theoretically, yes, the airline can deny you boarding if they are clear they require you to have a passport. However, if they did not communicate this requirement to you before you booking your ticket, they have very little to go on to enforce this requirement, when you don't need the passport to enter your destination country. Though, granted, when you are at the checkin desk, this will be little solace, indeed.

Comment: [RyanAir require passports or ID cards in lots of cases when they aren't legally required](https://www.ryanair.com/en/questions/do-i-need-a-visa/), as just one example, so I think the answer is "Yes, some airlines do impose additional requirements"

Comment: @pnuts I have arrived at my destination, the id card was fine

Answer (score 2):

According to Timatic, which is THE authority used by airlines for determining passport, visa & health requirements for travelers, your National ID is an acceptable travel document. [Timatic for Netherlands - Turkey](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=NL&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=TR&EM=NL&TR=00&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C)

Chances are the call center agent only looked at the general rules which state a passport is required, but the check in agent will be able to reference the full Timatic listing for your nationality - destination pair.  But to be ultra safe you could always print out a copy of the Timatic page and take it with you as a back up.

Timatic also goes on to state that Visas are required, but National ID holders can get a Visa on Arrival for 25 Euros.

Comment: I think based on my opening statement, it can be deduced that the answer to the OPs title is no (unless they are dealing with a non-IATA fly by night airline)

Comment: Pegasus is a member of IATA, why they do not appear in the online form linked to in the comments is unknown.

Comment: Thanks Tom. This is good to hear. At this point I have some of my confidence back, and I think everything will turn out fine.

Comment: Various airlines impose additional restrictions above and beyond the legal minimum. One such example is [RyanAir wanting passports on domestic flights when no legal requirement exists](https://www.ryanair.com/en/questions/do-i-need-a-visa/)